# MVC pattern controller responsibilities and best practice when presenting a view and transitioning through states

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, architecture

I am familiar with the concept of `MVC` in which we divide the concerns of modeling, presentation and processing of information. But when it comes to a real life example it gets hazy.

Lets take for example Apples `UITableView`. Say we have a coresponding controller which takes care of suplementing the table (the presented `UIView` is custom and just has a `UITableView`, exposed as a property, at the moment).

The `UITableView` has a property `backgroundView` which I want to use for displaying some info when there are no elements to display. The real question is where should it be suplemented?

1. Make a method in the custom view which creates the view and shows it (`showEmptyTableInfoViewWithMessage:`).
2. As in first example but just expose an `UILabel` as a property and make a simple hide/show method and work on the labels text property from the controller.
3. Create a custom `UIView` which will expose the `UILabel`. Alocate it and assign it to the backgroundView property in the controller.
4. Create a `UIView` with an `UILabel` rigt in the controller and assign it to the `backgroundView`.

As all of these examples will work I am wondering which one is the proper way (the best seperate of concerns / maintable way). I belive No. 4 is the worst but that is just my feeling at the moment.

Thank you in advance for any information on the best architectural design/approach.

Comment: Code Review does have a requirement where the code to be reviewed has to be included in the question. As it stands, this would get closed on CR. This could potentially be a good fit for programmers.stackexchange.com but if you do post there make sure you check their [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: I am more into checking what approach is best and not reviewing my approach that i've done (which i haven't yet).

Comment: I don't see how this is a particularly bad question for [so]....

Answer (score 0):

A `UIView` should be responsible for hiding or showing its subviews and managing its subviews.  It shouldn't be responsible for whether or not itself is visible.  That's why it exposes the `hidden` property--so outsiders can do this.

I don't like any of your four options personally.

---

I'd go with one of these two:

1. The `backgroundView` will already have a view object there.  We can just create a `UILabel` object and add it as a subview to the table view's default `backgroundView` and add the appropriate auto-layout constraints.  This would probably best be done by subclassing `UITableView`, and if so, I wouldn't expose a `UILabel` property, but rather expose an `NSString` property whose setter simply sets the label's text, and whose getter returns this text.  You may expose a few other methods perhaps for setting the label's font and a few other things.
2. Create a subclass of `UIView`, perhaps called `UIBackgroundView`.  This would be a `UIView` with a `UILabel` (and whatever else setup you want on it).  It shouldn't expose the label directly, but like before, it should instead expose properties that let you set the things about the label you might like to set and does it via proxy.  Then you instantiate it with a factory method something like this:

   ```
   vwBackground = [UIBackgroundView backgroundViewWithText:@"Hello World];
   ```

   And then simply:

   ```
   tableview.backgroundView = vwBackground;
   ```

---

Between the two options, which you use depends on what level of reusability you want.

Option one is probably slightly better, and it saves some coding after you've created the subclass, but obviously, you can only do this with table views.  If you want to do the same with a `UICollectionView`, or a `UIScrollView`, or a `UIImageView`, or whatever you can find that has a `backgroundView` property, you'd have to create similar subclasses for each... but in the end, it'd be easier and more intuitive to use, I feel.

But with option two, you can then automatically use your `UIBackgroundView` anywhere.  It's just a `UIView` with a label, and you can do with it anything you'd do with any other `UIView` object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Your option 2 is in fact very similar to my option 3. It just does not  expose the `UILabel` (just like in my 1 option). So it's kind o a mix. The reason I wanted to expose the `UIlabel` is for more versatility e.g. I can then choose to set the `NSMutableString` or the text property of the label and choose other customization options (Just like for example `UITableViewCells` expose the whole label and not just a setter for a message). Is that kind of exposure really bad?

Comment: From a strict MVC point of view, I don't think it's necessarily appropriate to expose the entire label.  It's hard to give a strict yes/no answer to "is that kind of exposure really bad?" without knowing much more specific details about your exact scenario.

Comment: My current scenario is that I would like to have the message customizable. That kind of customization can be achieved by a setter `setAttributedMessage:` and frankly that is all. I can then have probably multiline information with different fonts etc. As to your 1 option is kind of my 1 option. I Mean there is a custom UIView subclass that exposes the contained `UITableView` and in that view I can already set up a proper backgroundView for the `UITableView` during allocation. Then just add a `setMessage` method. The question is should the `VC` be responsible for setting the `bgView` (opt 2).